# PHP Date in past not match fit

Tags: php, date, time

First, I want to convert date to integer of PHP.

```
echo strtotime('08-04-2016 10:33:45 GMT+7');
```

and that's result: *1460086425*. But when I check again with code:

```
$timezone = +7;
echo gmdate("H:i:s | d-m-Y ",1460086425 + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
```

and that's result: `11:33:45 | 08-04-2016`

Why different from `11:33:45 | 08-04-2016` and `08-04-2016 10:33:45`, over one hour.

Comment: Change to echo gmdate("h:i:s | d-m-Y ",1460086425 + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));

Comment: $felipsmartins, thanks your help, but it still "11:33:45 | 08-04-2016". 

Deviation is one hour.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your timezone settings are not correct. I had a similar problem recently, and it was caused by the Daylight Saving Time not being applied correctly. I imagine that if the server does not know where it is, then it cannot know when DST starts and ends.

To find out of if this applies to you, try `echo ini_get('date.timezone');` in a script - what do you get? Be sure to do this either in a web context if your problem is in a web script, or on the console if your problem is on the console. This is because the PHP settings to control this are often set separately.

If you find that your setting does not give the correct city that you'd normally specify for your TZ, then change it in your `php.ini` file. For example, for me, I use this:

```
date.timezone = Europe/London
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (while checking [timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/)) the areas at GMT+7 do not observe DST. Also, `date` uses the timezone set in `date.timezone` which could be correct for your location but is probably incorrect for any other location.

It's better to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and specify the correct [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php). That way the chances of getting the time zone offset (and whether or not DST is active) wrong are significantly reduced.